# Assign a cost to a link

Tags: netlogo

I have a landscape where each patch contains a cost value. 
I placed a turtle within each patch according to the following code :

```
to create-turtles 
ask neighbors [ sprout 1 [ 
set shape "dot" 
set size 0.5 ] ]
end
```

Then, I built a link between each turtle according to the following code :

```
to create-link-turtles
ask turtles [ create-links-with turtles-on neighbors ]
end
```

As each patch contains a cost value, I would like to assign a cost value to links between turtles.

For example,
If the link intersects two patches (patches 1 and 2) that have two different costs, the link would be equal to cost in patch 1 + cost in patch 2.

If the link intersects two patches (patches 1 and 2) that have the same cost, the link would be equal to cost in patch 1.

How can I assign a cost value to links between turtles in this way ?

After this, I would like to apply the dijkstra' s algorithm.

Thank you for your help.
Have a good day

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

- your patches have a `cost` variable
- your links have a `link-cost` variable
- turtles are always connected to turtles on neighboring patches (like in the code you posted)

You can simply :

```
ask links [ set link-cost sum [ cost ] of both-ends ]
```

This will just add the costs of the two patches under the turtles at both ends of the link. (If you had links traversing more than two patches, this approach would not work and things would get much more complicated.)

For calculating distances afterwards, I'd suggest you take a look at [the NW extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension#readme). Its [`weighted-distance-to` primitive](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/#distance-to-weighted-distance-to) uses Dijktra's algorithm internally.